# How can I have one password for FileValue 2 (pre-boot password) and another for my user login?

Tags: filevault

I know this is possible.

When I first installed Mavericks, I set up a default password of "password".

I then enabled Filevault 2.

At some point I then changed my password from "password" to my actual password.

However the pre-boot password is still "password".

I like the fact that there were two different passwords, but I want to change the pre-boot password to something better than "password" (obviously!) but...

How?

On my laptop, I've done some testing and changing the user login password also updates the pre-boot password.

And if I fail the pre-boot password 3 times and use the recovery key, I can update the  password, but it only updates the user login password, which in turn automatically updates the pre-boot password.

So they are always in sync.

So how on earth did I originally have 2 different passwords, and how can I continue to have 2 different passwords?

Answer (score 5):

As you've found, there's an sync process when you change your password that automatically updates your account login at the FileVault 2 pre-boot login screen. However, if you're OK with having to login twice, there's a way to set the FileVault 2 login process on Mavericks so that you're stopped at the OS login window after logging in at the FileVault 2 login window.

The way to do this is to disable FileVault 2's automatic login, which is the process that the OS uses to automatically log you into your account after you've logged in at the FileVault 2 pre-boot login screen. Apple has a KBase article here that shows how to do this:

[OS X: How to disable automatic login when FileVault is enabled](https://web.archive.org/web/20140311021508/http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5989)

> ###### Passwords
>
> When disabling automatic login, two passwords are required while starting up:
>
> One password is needed to unlock the disk at the EFI Login Window.
> Another password is needed to log in at the regular Login Window.
> These passwords can be the same if you are logging in as the user who unlocked the disk.
>
> ###### Command line
>
> Use the following command to disable automatic login when FileVault is enabled:
>
> ```
> sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow DisableFDEAutoLogin -bool YES
> ```
>
> Use the following command to allow automatic login when FileVault is enabled:
>
> ```
> sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow DisableFDEAutoLogin
> ```

Once you've disabled automatic login, set up a new local account on your Mac and set it to use a different password from your account's password. New local accounts should be automatically enabled for FileVault 2 access, so you shouldn't need to do anything else. Since this second account is only going to be used as a FileVault 2 login, I'd recommend making it a standard user with no admin privileges.

After that, reboot your Mac and login at the FileVault 2 pre-boot login screen using your new account's password. When the OS unlocks and boots, you should then be stopped at the OS login window. At that point, login with your regular username and password.

Comment: Ah, very cool but at the moment I have:
- 1 admin account
- pre-boot login where "password" ONLY works
- user login of my normal password
- no automatic login - I have to select my admin user to login

HOW I got that I don't know, but I like that (except I want to change my pre-boot password)

I want it so I can give someone my pre-boot password but that password won't work on my admin account.

Your solution is great but it means if someone has my pre-boot password, they also have my user login password.

Comment: After adding the second account, you could remove your user account from the FileVault 2 pre-boot login screen by using the following command in Terminal: 

`sudo fdesetup remove -user your_username_goes_here`

That would allow only the second account to show up at the pre-boot login screen. You would login with that password, stop at the OS login window and then login with your username and password.

Comment: Excellent, thanks Rich... I haven't implemented that but it makes perfect sense.