# Is the Yosemite File Vault password (usually) the same as login password?

Tags: macos, password, filevault

So when I upgraded to Yosemite, I can remember turning on FileVault. I cannot remember the password I used. Is that password is the same as my login password for my administrator account (the only account on the computer)?

I'm nervous that I will one day have to remember that password, and if it isn't the one I'm already using, I might be in trouble. I've searched around for the answer, but I'm not finding anything. I might just not be describing the correct dialogue box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X will usually attempt to sync the password if you change it, but it's possible to have them different. I have them differently right now, so that my old user password is required at the pre-boot screen, but once OS X is booted, I need to log in again with my new password.

See more info in this answer: [How can I have one password for FileValue 2 (pre-boot password) and another for my user login?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125087/how-can-i-have-one-password-for-filevalue-2-pre-boot-password-and-another-for)

Answer (score 2):

If your password isn't the same as your login and you can't remember it, there are directions for either retrieving your recovery key from Apple or changing your key in this Knowledge Base Article: [About Filevault 2](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4790)